# Webpack doesn't babelize some node_modules with ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have been having issues with webpack and some node_modules libraries not being "babelized" in the outputed bundle. Most notably ES6 syntax such as 'const'.

Up until now I would solve this problem by including the specific libraries that would create that issue in the babel-loader path to force their babelization. However in this particular case, the unbabelized code seems to come from a library that isn't in my package.json, which means it must be nested in another library.

How can I track down from which library that nested library comes from ?

Or is there a simpler solution to ensure that the entirety of my modules don't remain in ES6 form ?

Below is my webpack.config.js file :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/public/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js');
var CSS_DIR = path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'css');

var config_function = function(env){
var config = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/index.js'],
output: {
  path: BUILD_DIR,
  filename: env && env.prod ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
},
plugins: env && env.prod ? [
  new UglifyJSPlugin({uglifyOptions:{
        ecma: 5,
        mangle: {
            safari10: true
        },
        compress: true
      }})
]: [],
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    include: [APP_DIR, /node_modules\/snakecase-keys/, /node_modules\/redux-api-middleware/,/node_modules\/map-obj/], // Those are some of the libraries that are not babelized...
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'] //, 'react-hmre']
    }
  }
  , {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  }, {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  }, {
    test: /\.less$/,
    include: CSS_DIR,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
  },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
  ]
}
  };

  return config;
}

module.exports = config_function;
```

Comment: "How can I track down from which library that nested library comes from?" -> Search in your bundle for "const", then copy the line of code and search for it in your project directory files (including node_modules).

Comment: Realized that my editor would not search through .gitignore folders which is why I couldn't do project directory search... Thanks for your answer !